# Enforce: Command Not Found - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apparmor

When I tried to run the code below:

```
enforce /etc/apparmor.d/*
```

It says:

```
enforce: command not found
```

Even if I already successfully installed `apparmor-utils` using the code below:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

The command is from CIS Distribution Independent Linux Manual (page 94):

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this command? Maybe `aa-enforce`?

Comment: @Pilot6 --> It is the command I read in a manual for apparmor package.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this manual?

Comment: This must be a wrong manual for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 --> the manual can be downloaded for free when we logged in to https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/ . The title is CIS Distribution Independent Linux

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong manual for Ubuntu.

Ubuntu manual for Apparmor can be found [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apparmor.html.en).

Most likely you are looking for `aa-enforce` command.